# How to save UTC (instead of local) timestamps for Hibernate Envers revision info?

Tags: hibernate, timestamp, utc, hibernate-envers

Using Hibernate/Envers, how to:

1. Save UTC (instead of local) timestamps for Hibernate Envers revision info?
2. Get timestamps as a LocalDateTime (Java 8)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) From the revision listener, call the `fixTimezone` method of the revision, as shown below.

2) To get it as `LocalDateTime` use the `getRevisionDate` method, as shown below.

```
public class MyRevisionListener
    implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        MyRevision revision = (MyRevision)revisionEntity;
        revision.fixTimezone();
        }
    }

@Entity
@RevisionEntity (MyRevisionListener.class)
public class MyRevision
      implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private long id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Temporal (TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    private static final ZoneId ZONE_ID_UTC = ZoneId.of("UTC");

    public void fixTimezone() {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZONE_ID_UTC);
        date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        }

    @NotNull
    public LocalDateTime getRevisionDate() {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }

    ...
    }
```

Related Hibernate issues:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10828
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10827
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10496