# Convert BigInt date into a Date

Tags: java

So Our database has a column BigInt REVISIONTS  used as part of java Hibernate Envers

It initially contained timestamps from Java Date.

E.g)  `ts=1561637560383`
I used to convert to Date using `new Date(ts)`

But since Date cannot contain timezones and we needed UTC date, we had to store UTC directly as BigInt and applied a fix suggested by hibernate. Because of this now our timestamps are like this

E.g)  `ts=20190827202449` now this is not a timestamp anymore but an actual UTC LocaleDateTime stored as bigint

Now querying this i get long and if I use `new Date(ts)` i am getting incorrect date of course since this is not a timestamp but Hibernate Date with Temporal.Timestamp stored the UTC as is.

I am thinking of converting Long to string and use formatting to convert back when retrieving.

Are there any other cleaner method of converting ?

UTC fix for Envers

[How to save UTC (instead of local) timestamps for Hibernate Envers revision info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748142/how-to-save-utc-instead-of-local-timestamps-for-hibernate-envers-revision-info)

Comment: So maybe I'm missing something, but your original solution was an offset from the Linux Epoch. Offsets don't have timezones, true, but you can get the value in a particular time zone pretty easily.

Comment: That being said, are you stuck on Java 7 or newer, is that why you're relying java.util.Date and not the time libraries introduced in Java 8 and newer?

Comment: If you have the time in UTC, it should be pretty easy to convert it to anything else.

Comment: *"But since Date cannot contain timezones and we needed UTC date"* — Isn't that the whole point of UTC? A timezone-insensitive representation of an instant?

Comment: The original solution converted from whatever was in Java 7 Date. When I read about Date I heard that it doesnt guarantee you UTC when saving and it uses JVM time zone . We are not stuck in Java 7 but Hibernate Envers doesn't support all latest java 8 SO I. Updated my question with the fix suggested.

Comment: *"Date cannot contain timezones and we needed UTC date"* `java.util.Date` is always in UTC.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `Date` at all. Never. Ever.

I think storing the time as a Unix Timestamp is pretty fine. They're always in UTC and represent a unique instant on the timeline.

Envers supports both `Date` and `Long`/`long` to be defined as revision timestamp. You should use `Long`.

Formatting it using a timezone or timezone offset can be easily done with the newer Java Date and Time API available in the `java.time` package.

With `Instant.ofEpochSecond(yourTimestamp)` you can create an `Instant`. With `atOffset` or `atZone` you can combine the bare timestamp with a certain timezone or timezone offset.

Answer (score 3):

Your Question is quite unclear. But this might help.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> to convert to Date using new Date(ts)

Never use `java.util.Date`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically by `Instant`.

## `Instant`

> E.g)  ts=1561637560383

You are not clear about exactly what that value represents. I will guess it is a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
long count = 1_561_637_560_383L ;
```

If that is a textual value, parse using [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) class.

```
long count = Long.parseLong( "1561637560383" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( count ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/QuhpJX).

> instant.toString(): 2019-06-27T12:12:40.383Z

Tip: In your database, store date-time values using date-time data type.

If your database is too primitive to support date-time types, store as text in UTC using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Ex: 2019-06-27T12:12:40.383Z
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-06-27T12:12:40.383Z" ) ;
```

Get count of milliseconds since epoch reference.

```
long count = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

## Convert

When you must use `Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. Call new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;
```

Comment: Had to use Date because Envers did not support at that time